# How can I test the same site from IE8 / 9 / 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, virtual-machine

The test should be done on the **real** internet explorer because it's not about the web graphic but about the caching system.

Is it possible to login to **remote hosted virtual machine** having different web browser installed and test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your site on different browsers on your computer with virtual machines.

Microsoft provide the ["Virtual PC"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4580) that can run virtual operation systems on your computer.

Also gives the give [VHDs for Windows Virtual PC, for testing websites with different Internet Explorer versions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575). VHD, is the file that Virtual PC loads and run the system.

At that moment MS, gives tests for IE6,7,8, and 9 versions.

Also there is one site that provide this service, and have a free period of use

the https://saucelabs.com/

there you can see almost all os and all browsers and make your tests. Is an advanced system that gives too many options that you can use, including automation on your testing. This site do the same, runs virtual machines for you on their server and gives to you, via the web site the ability to how your site is loaded there.